# Regular Expression For Time Format Like DD:HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript, regex, time

I am trying to do Validation for a time based text box. In that i need a Format like this.
`00:00:00:00` (`Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds`).
Valid Times are `99:23:59:59, 01:01:01:01, 25:00:20:55`,

Invalid Times are `99:24:60:60, 99:2:1:1`

I don't have much knowledge in Regex. So can anyone help me to build a Regex which matches for my Scenario ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern,

```
^\d{2}:([0-1]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)$
```

- [See This](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29622718/regex2.JPG)

Brief Explanation:

- Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) `^`
- Match a single digit 0..9 `\d{2}`

  - Exactly 2 times `{2}`
- Match the character “:” literally `:`
- Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 `([0-1]\d|2[0-3])`

  - Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) `[0-1]\d`

    - Match a single character in the range between “0” and “1” `[0-1]`
    - Match a single digit 0..9 `\d`
  - Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) `2[0-3]`

    - Match the character “2” literally `2`
    - Match a single character in the range between “0” and “3” `[0-3]`
- Match the character “:” literally `:`
- Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 `([0-5]\d)`

  - Match a single character in the range between “0” and “5” «[0-5]»
  - Match a single digit 0..9 `\d`
- Match the character “:” literally `:`
- Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «([0-5]\d)»

  - Match a single character in the range between “0” and “5” `[0-5]`
  - Match a single digit 0..9 `\d`
- Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) `$`

Comment: Can I do replace with ''(null) when other characters entered? In Which way I can do this? or I have to check whether pattern is matching or not? all what I need is at key pressing time only I have to restrict the User.